# How to get the numbers after string "tag=" in php

Tags: php

I'd like to get the numbers after "tag=".

for example in the case below, I'd like to get number '123'

```php
<li><a href='http://example.com/2019/?tag=123'>2019 &nbsp;(3)</a></li>
<li><a href='http://example.com/2018/?tag=123'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>
<li><a href='http://example.com/2017/?tag=123'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>
<li><a href='http://example.com/2016/?tag=123'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>
```

Digit could change but all listed numbers would be same.
Domain and year after domain could change.

I tried something like below, but I'm stuck.

```html
$get_number = explode("<li><a href='http://example.com/", $get_number);
$get_number = substr($get_number, ...);
```

Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `nsregularexpression`? That's a class for iOS and macOS development and have nothing to do with PHP. If you simply meant `regular expressions`, then you should show us what you've tried (using regex, that is). We're happy to help you fix your existing code, but we won't do all the work for you.

Comment: Combination of [DOM parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) should work

Answer (score 1):

ok, you can do this in below ways:

- get all tags grouped by years

```php
$str = '<li><a href=\'http://example.com/2019/?tag=123\'>2019 &nbsp;(3)</a></li>
<li><a href=\'http://example.com/2018/?tag=123\'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>
<li><a href=\'http://example.com/2017/?tag=123\'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>
<li><a href=\'http://example.com/2016/?tag=123\'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/\/(?<years>[0-9]+)\/\?tag=(?<tags>[0-9]+)/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches['years'], $matches['tags']);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/bLob7

- just get all tags by this pattern

```php
$str = '<li><a href=\'http://example.com/2019/?tag=123\'>2019 &nbsp;(3)</a></li>
<li><a href=\'http://example.com/2018/?tag=123\'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>
<li><a href=\'http://example.com/2017/?tag=123\'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>
<li><a href=\'http://example.com/2016/?tag=123\'>2018 &nbsp;(1)</a></li>';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/tag=(?<tags>[0-9]+)/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches['tags']);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/NT4Lo

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure of your full document structure, but you can use DOMDocument to do most of the work.  In this example it uses `getElementsByTagName()` to get all `<a>` tags, but if you need anything more complicated, you can use XPath to find the relevant items.

This then extracts the `href` attribute and splits the query part out (using `parse_url()` and `PHP_URL_QUERY` to get `tag=123`) and then uses `parse_str()` to extract an asociative array of the values...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$aTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach ( $aTags as $tag )  {
    parse_str(parse_url($tag->getAttribute("href"), PHP_URL_QUERY), $parts);
    echo $parts['tag'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and dirty:

```
$result = array_filter(array_map('intval', explode('tag=', $string)));
```

RegExp (numbers are inside `$result[1]`):

```
preg_match_all("#tag=(\d+)#", $string, $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It may fulfill ur requirement

```html
<?php


$a = new SimpleXMLElement('<a href="http://example.com/2019/?tag=123">Click here</a>');
$href= $a['href'];

$whatIWant = substr($href, strpos($href, "=") + 1);    
echo $whatIWant;
?>
```